# Entity Framework: Multiple navigation properties from same model causing error when adding migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model called `TypeListItem` w/ three properties `(Id, TypeListId, Name)` that contains a bunch of lists.

**For example:**

> ProductType: Strong, Weak, Medium
>
> ProductCategory: Category 1, Category 2, Category 3

I have a Product model that looks like this:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public int ProductTypeId {get; set;}  
public int ProductCategoryId {get; set;}

// Navigation Properties
public TypeListItem ProductType {get; set;}
public TypeListItem ProductCategory {get; set;}
```

However, when I go to add a migration and then `dotnet ef database update`' I get an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint :
>   FK_Product_TypeListItem_ProductCategoryId on table 'Product' may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths.

I also have the following using fluent api:

```
builder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.ProductTypeId)
    .IsRequired();
builder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.ProductCategoryId)
    .IsRequired();
```

I believe the error is because I have two navigation properties that use the same object and both are required.

Any recommendations? Is there something wrong with my model?

**Does something like this make sense for ef core?**

```
    builder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasOne(p => p.ProductType)
        .WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasOne(p => p.ProductCategory)
        .WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: can you show the code of `TypeListItem` ?

Comment: There is nothing to it. Just Id, TypeListId, and Name properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use   `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` as shown below.

**Note :**

> **Restrict :** The delete operation is not applied to dependent entities.
>   The dependent entities remain unchanged.

```
builder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.ProductTypeId)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.ProductCategoryId)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

You can see more here : [**Cascade Delete**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/live/entity-framework/core/modeling/relationships.md#cascade-delete-1)

Comment: I believe this is the answer for EF6, but I need to be able to do it with EF Core and I think they changed the syntax. Please see my updated post. Do you think the empty WithOne() makes sense? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?highlight=cascade#cascade-delete

Comment: I don't think the syntax in your answer is valid. I believe you can't join IsRequired and WithOne together in the same statement. Otherwise answer is correct.